# For two dataframes , how to retrieve rows where a combination of two label values is in one but not the other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my python application, I have two dataframes with the following labels:

```
df1:: page, origin, count

df2:: page, claim, verdict, origin
```

Where:

Each specific page can have many origins and origins might repeat for different pages:

> df1 contains a large list of all pages and their associated origins (so same page can repeat)
>
> df2 contains details of the page-origin combinations accessed by the user
>
> ---

What I want to do is, using `.loc` I presume, get all the rows from `df1` that have not been accessed by a certain user. I want to use `page-origin` as some sort of primary key to remove all corresponding rows in `df2` from `df1`.

So for example:

```
df1:
  page       origin     count
www.h1.com  www.h1.com    2
www.h1.com  www.h2.com    1
www.h2.com  www.h1.com    0
www.h3.com  www.h4.com    4
```

and

```
df2:
  page           claim           verdict     origin     count
www.h1.com | the world is flat |  false  |  www.h1.com    2
www.h1.com | the world is flat |  false  |  www.h2.com    3
```

would give:

```
   page       origin    count
www.h2.com  www.h1.com    0
www.h3.com  www.h4.com    4
```

Comment: You need `.isin`

Comment: So something like : df1= df1.loc[~(df1['page']+df1['origin']).isin(df2)]? Will that work

Comment: In df2 you want to check on both page and origin?

Comment: Yes. I want to use page origin as some sort of 2-label primary key. Since, on their own, they are not unique.

Comment: `df1['page']+df1['origin']`, no. This is just adding the strings . And for `.isin(df2.page)`, in which columns? All of them?

Comment: Small error, use `df1[~(df1.page.isin(df2.page) & df1.origin.isin(df2.origin))] `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @yatu for the answer, which was to use

```
df1[~(df1.page.isin(df2.page) & df1.origin.isin(df2.origin))]
```